# Error using Javascript modules Webpack. Function methods not working ("is not a function" error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, webpack, module

I'm just getting started working with webpack, but I'm stumped at a rather simple problem.

To try to solve it, I've been looking around the web, but for some reason I can't find examples using vanilla javascript function methods with webpack. I have no problem exporting, importing, and executing imported functions.

The problem is I can't execute imported **function methods**, and I don't understand why.
The functions are imported correctly, and can be executed. The methods cannot be executed.

In this case, I can execute model(), but when I try to call model.alertone(), I get the error "model.alertone is not a function".

Here is the code:

model.js:

```js
function model() {

    var alertone = () => {alert("This works")};


    return {
        alertone
    }

 };

export default model;
```

index.js:

```js
import model from "./model.js";


model();
model.alertone();
```

Webpack configuration:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem with webpack; this is a problem with your program. Why?

Well, first of all, you wrote your `model` function to return an object, like so:

```js
function model() {
  // Define the 
  var alertone = () => {alert("This works")};

  // Return an object
  return {
    alertone
  }
};
```

Then, you imported the `model` function, and called it:

```js
model();
model.alertone();
```

But there's a problem with that. The `model` function ***returns*** an object, but it doesn't add any properties to the `model` function itself. Because of that, the `model` function will have no properties (except for the native ones), and so you can't call `alertone`.

You probably meant to do this:

```js
var result = model();
result.alertone();
```

That's all you need to do.

Comment: This solved it. Thank you for saving me from madness. What a dumb mistake. Thank you so much! 

If you have any recommendations on terms / concepts I should read up on, I would appreciate  it. From your answer and a quick search, maybe that would be Prototyping.